# VLC web plugin initially won't show in IE8 or IE9

Tags: internet-explorer, plugins, activex, vlc

This is already a [registered bug](http://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/6918#comment:2) at VLC's Trac, but no suggested solution has been proposed, it seems. I couldn't comment there either (got an internal Trac error) so I'll just paste the solution (or well, what works for me) here. Note that the ticket reports it's working in IE8, but that was not the case for me. I have VLC 1.1.9 installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have the following embed tag:

```
<object id="playerId" classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921" width="752" height="578">
```

My working example is as follows, assuming JQuery:

```
$(function() {
    var player = document.getElementById("playerId");
    var playlist = player.playlist;
    playlist.clear();
    var id = playlist.add("rtsp://yoururl", "", new Array());
    playlist.playItem(id);

    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#playerId").hide().show();
    }, 100);
});
```

I'm using IE8 right now, don't ask why... I'm not using this horrible browser regularly, but I'm trapped in a requirement-for-windows-and-old-IE-browsers-and-needs-vlc-plugin-hell. When I solved it I actually thought I heard the [Guile theme](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jLJLyneZGKc) in the background, but I guess that was just my imagination. Anyways, I hope someone else can benefit from this.